# Register multiple partials from single HTML *string*

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, partials

Imagine, I have a string containing multiple HTML partials, like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ratings/down">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"
        style="position: absolute; color: red; font-size: 2em; left: .6em; top: .3em;"></i>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="ratings/up">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"
        style="position: absolute; color: #77AA33; font-size: 2em; left: .6em; top: .3em;"></i>
</script>
```

Note that this is not currently part of the DOM. It is in a string variable. Can I somehow, easily, have all partials registered with [the `$templateCache` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache), and without custom string manipulation? Imagine that the HTML string is a whole lot more complex, as to totally abandon the string manipulation idea. I was hoping that there is a simpler way to do this? I am getting the feeling that I won't get around fiddling with `$compile`...

Comment: You may be able to do it by parsing the string as HTML, then iterating over the `<script>` elements from the DOM and then manually registering the inner text of each script with the `$templateCache`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Yeah I was hoping to avoid that - But, short of other ideas, I am working on just that, as we speak :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/25Ff1IOGdbMrzPtRWcGQ?p=preview):

```
var string = '<script type="text/ng-template" id="ratings/down"> \
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" \
        style="color: red; font-size: 2em; left: .6em; top: .3em;">rating down</i> \
    </script> \
 \
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="ratings/up"> \
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" \
        style="position: absolute; color: #77AA33; font-size: 2em; left: .6em; top: .3em;"></i> \
    </script>'

var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = string;

for (var i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++){
    var temp = div.children[i];
    $templateCache.put(temp.id, temp.innerHTML);
}
```

We create a fake div to make the parsing for us.

Remark: *This logic should be put in a separate service.*

Comment: Yeah, I ended up with a very similar solution. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: I guess, I would have hoped that `$templateCache` had that built-in :P